# Tags anchor não funcionam dentro de figcaption:target?

Tags: html, css, css3

Fiz um menu animado em *CSS3* utilizando a tag `figure`, na qual inseri uma imagem com o link que utilizei como id na tag `figcaption`. Dentro de `figcaption` está a minha lista com a listagem de links para acessar outras páginas. No meu arquivo .css, `figcaption` está com `opacity:0;` e `visibility:none;` enquanto que `figcaption:target` está com `opacity:1;` e `visibility:visible;`.

Acontece que os links que inseri na minha lista dentro da tag `figcaption` não estão funcionando. Por que?

Arquivo CSS:

```
.menu figcaption{opacity: 0; visibility: none;}

.menu figcaption:target{opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}
```

E no .php:

```
figure
   a href="#abrir"
      img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu"
   /a

   figcaption id="abrir"
      ul
         li
            a href="index.php"
               Página Inicial
            /a
         ...
```

Comment: @Florida CSS3 foi removida do titulo pois já consta como tag, o que facilita a busca posteriormente.

Comment: Eu havia feito a edição ao mesmo tempo que você, por isso não pude ver que você já tinha enviado @diegofm